# Sentence capitalization exception

Tags: javascript, regex, string, uppercase, capitalization

I have this script which capitalizes the first letter of each sentence:

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.replace(/.+?[\.\?\!](\s|$)/g, function (txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.slice(1);
    });
};
```

I want to add an exception: the first word of the sentence after `.`, `?`, and `!` characters should not be capitalized if the character is preceded by an `xy` word.

In my case from `capitalization of string xy. is not correct.` will be `Capitalization of string xy. Is not correct.`

I want as a result: `Capitalization of string xy. is not correct.`

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't try to solve this with regex. JS does not support lookbehind.

Comment: @Bergi Is it possible to lowercase the word after `xy.`?

Comment: Sure it's possible, but you should not try to by adapting your replacement regex.

Comment: You might just use `[.?!]` since there is no need to escape it. Good luck understanding [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/uS6iM5) `/(?:(?!xy).|.xy[.?!])+?[.?!](?:\s|$)/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds, you'll have a much easier time going through exactly the function you've written and then arbitrarily correcting the mistakenly capitalized bits back to lowercase.

Working example:

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function(exception) {
    var result = this.replace(/.+?[\.\?\!](\s|$)/g, function (txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.slice(1);
    });
    var r = new RegExp(exception + "\\.\\s*\(\\w+\)", "i");
    return result.replace(r, function(re) { return(re.toLowerCase()) });
};

alert("capitalization of string xy. is not correct.".capitalize("xy"));
```

You probably could enhance it to handle an array of exceptions, or even use a regular expression.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/4EZBb/

Comment: …but it would need to be the next match that is lowercased!

Comment: Yeah, I though about that way as well but realized I could not distinguish erroneously uppercased word from those that were intentionally capitalized in the input (e.g. `"xy. Incorrect!".capitalize("xy") == "xy. incorrect!"`). Of course that's an edge case and might not need to be handled, but I found it impure :-)

Comment: @Bergi I think since xy is probably something like an abbreviation (like `etc.`) it would rarely be. But probably close enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
String.prototype.capitalizeSentencesWithout = function(word) {
    return this.replace(/.+?[\.\?\!](?:\s|$)/g, function (txt, pos, orig) {
        if (orig.slice(pos-word.length-2, pos-2) == word)
            return txt;
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.slice(1);
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
> "capitalization of string xy. is correct.".capitalizeSentencesWithout("xy")
"Capitalization of string xy. is correct."
```

You could also solve this by making your `.+?` expression greedily consume the `xy` word, but that would get much more complicated.